# spring authentication using react.js sends gibberish response

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a application in react.js and it's server is in spring boot.

Now I want to implement OAuth2 for user authentication. If user is authenticated, then app can get response from the server.

In my application.properties I have added these:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-id=somekey
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-secret=somekeyhere`
```

In pom.xml I have added these:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have create WebSecurityConfiguration like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

When I try to get any requests like `/user` in browser it redirects me to login or to create account and everything works fine.

But the problem is I can't use the react.js application anymore, so how can I make the authentication in client portion?

Comment: have you solved the problem, have you checked your `redirecting urls` that you have registered project. it must redirect to url after successful login

Comment: @AshishKamble i have tried a lot and couldn't figure it out.. yes redirect url is correct, localhost:3000/home

Comment: have you tried `@EnableOauth2Sso`, you can post your all redirecting urls here in question please, does it include any `code=...something...`, I think `localhost:8080` is your spring app and `localhost:3000` is react app, Right